# Error al Serializar

Tags: vb.net, .net, xml, serialización

A partir de un XML quiero conseguir el xsd para obtener mi clase en vb .net o C# y así poder cargar cualquier xml que me envíen. He probado con varias herramientas web para conseguir el xsd y después he generado la clase con Xsd2Code pero obtengo el siguiente error al intentar obtener el XmlSerializer.

> Additional information: Error al cargar el ensamblado con el nombre
>   para mostrar 'xxxxxx.XmlSerializers' en el contexto de enlace
>   'LoadFrom' de AppDomain con ID 1. Error debido a:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No se puede cargar el archivo o
>   ensamblado 'xxxxxx.XmlSerializers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede
>   encontrar el archivo especificado.

También he probado a obtener directamente la clase con el xml sin pasar por el xsd pero el resultado es el mismo.

Os dejo un XML de ejemplo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xxxxxOutputData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FinalProduct>
    <Code>Codigo</Code>
    <Description1Translation>
      <Language>es-ES</Language>
      <Description1>xxx xxxx</Description1>
    </Description1Translation>
    <Description2>xxxxxx de xxx</Description2>
    <Description3>xxx,xxx,xxxx</Description3>
    <Version>3</Version>
    <EmissionDate>2014-05-23</EmissionDate>
    <ReviewDate>2015-08-20</ReviewDate>
    <Family>4</Family>
    <Brand>xxx</Brand>
    <Company>
      <Name>Nombre</Name>
      <TaxCode>Axxxxxxx</TaxCode>
      <Adress>Direccion</Adress>
      <City>Poblacion</City>
      <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
      <Province>Provincia</Province>
      <Country>Pais</Country>
      <Phone>+34123456789</Phone>
      <Fax>+34123456789</Fax>
      <Email>xxx@xxxx.es</Email>
      <Web>www.xxxx.es</Web>
    </Company>
    <Market>2</Market>
    <Market>3</Market>
    <ApplicationMethod>27</ApplicationMethod>
    <Substance>
      <CasNumber>111-111-11</CasNumber>
      <EcNumber>111-111-11</EcNumber>
      <ReachNumber>111-111-11</ReachNumber>
      <Translation>
        <Language>es-ES</Language>
        <Name>xxxxx de xxxx</Name>
      </Translation>
    </Substance>
    <Ingredient>
      <MixtureCode>MP_010</MixtureCode>
      <Percentage>100.000000000000000</Percentage>
    </Ingredient>
    <PhysicoChemicals>
      <PhysicalState20>1</PhysicalState20>
      <MeltingPoint>1010.000000000000000</MeltingPoint>
      <TemperatureDependent>
        <Temperature>20</Temperature>
        <Density>2.970000000000000</Density>
        <RelativeDensity>2.970000000000000</RelativeDensity>
      </TemperatureDependent>
    </PhysicoChemicals>
    <Reach>
      <RphrasesEdited>false</RphrasesEdited>
      <Rphrases>
        <Rphrase>
          <Code>R20</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxx por xxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Rphrase>
        <Rphrase>
          <Code>xxxx/xxxx/xxxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxx: xx de xx xx para xx xx en xx de xx xx por xx e xx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Rphrase>
        <Rphrase>
          <Code>xx/xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xx para xx xx xx, xx xx a xx xx xx xx en el xx xx xx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Rphrase>
      </Rphrases>
      <SphrasesEdited>false</SphrasesEdited>
      <Sphrases>
        <Sphrase>
          <Code>xx/2</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xx bajo xx y xx xx del xx de los xx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Sphrase>
        <Sphrase>
          <Code>xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xx xx del xx de los xx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Sphrase>
        <Sphrase>
          <Code>xxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>No xx el xx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Sphrase>
        <Sphrase>
          <Code>xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xx xx xx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Sphrase>
        <Sphrase>
          <Code>xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xx xx de xx o xx, xx xx al xx (si es xx, xx la xx)</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Sphrase>
        <Sphrase>
          <Code>S61</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xx su xx al xx xx xx xx xx de la xx de xx de xx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Sphrase>
      </Sphrases>
      <Symbols>
        <Symbol>
          <Code>N</Code>
          <ColourPictogram>xxxx</ColourPictogram>
          <BlackPictogram>xxxxx</BlackPictogram>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxx xxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Symbol>
        <Symbol>
          <Code>T</Code>
          <ColourPictogram>xxxx</ColourPictogram>
          <BlackPictogram>xxxxxx</BlackPictogram>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Symbol>
      </Symbols>
    </Reach>
    <Clp>
      <HazardCategoriesEdited>false</HazardCategoriesEdited>
      <HazardCategories>
        <HazardCategory>
          <Code>xxxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
          <Hphrase>
            <Code>xx</Code>
            <Translation>
              <Language>es-ES</Language>
              <Description>xxxx</Description>
            </Translation>
          </Hphrase>
        </HazardCategory>
        <HazardCategory>
          <Code>xx xx 2</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
          <Hphrase>
            <Code>xx</Code>
            <Translation>
              <Language>es-ES</Language>
              <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
            </Translation>
          </Hphrase>
        </HazardCategory>
        <HazardCategory>
          <Code>xxxxxxxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
          <Hphrase>
            <Code>xx</Code>
            <Translation>
              <Language>es-ES</Language>
              <Description>xxxx</Description>
            </Translation>
          </Hphrase>
        </HazardCategory>
        <HazardCategory>
          <Code>xx xx 1</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
          <Hphrase>
            <Code>xxx</Code>
            <Translation>
              <Language>es-ES</Language>
              <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
            </Translation>
          </Hphrase>
        </HazardCategory>
      </HazardCategories>
      <PphrasesEdited>false</PphrasesEdited>
      <Pphrases>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xxxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xxxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xx+xx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
        <Pphrase>
          <Code>xxx</Code>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pphrase>
      </Pphrases>
      <PriorityWarning>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>Peligro</Description>
        </Translation>
      </PriorityWarning>
      <Pictograms>
        <Pictogram>
          <Code>xxxx</Code>
          <ColourPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ColourPictogram>
          <BlackPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</BlackPictogram>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pictogram>
        <Pictogram>
          <Code>xxx</Code>
          <ColourPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ColourPictogram>
          <BlackPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</BlackPictogram>
        </Pictogram>
        <Pictogram>
          <Code>xxxxxx</Code>
          <ColourPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ColourPictogram>
          <BlackPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</BlackPictogram>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Description>xxxxx</Description>
          </Translation>
        </Pictogram>
      </Pictograms>
    </Clp>
    <Label>
      <Reach>
        <Substance>
          <xxxxxID>xx</xxxxxID>
          <CasNumber>xx-xx-6</CasNumber>
          <EcNumber>xx-xx-6</EcNumber>
          <ReachNumber>xx-xx-xx-XXXX</ReachNumber>
          <Translation>
            <Language>es-ES</Language>
            <Name>xx de xx</Name>
          </Translation>
        </Substance>
      </Reach>
    </Label>
    <Adr>
      <UnNumber>xx</UnNumber>
      <Translation>
        <Language>es-ES</Language>
        <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
      </Translation>
      <Class>9</Class>
      <ClassPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ClassPictogram>
      <PackingGroup>xxx</PackingGroup>
      <Label>9</Label>
      <TransportCategory>3</TransportCategory>
      <EnvironmentallyHazardous>true</EnvironmentallyHazardous>
      <EnvironmentallyHazardousPictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</EnvironmentallyHazardousPictogram>
      <LimitedQuantity>5.000000000000000</LimitedQuantity>
      <LimitedQuantityUnit>kg</LimitedQuantityUnit>
    </Adr>
    <Imdg>
      <FemCode>F-A</FemCode>
      <FemCode>S-F</FemCode>
    </Imdg>
    <Descomposition>
      <Substance>
        <xxxxxID>xx</xxxxxID>
        <CasNumber>xx-xx-6</CasNumber>
        <EcNumber>xx-xx-6</EcNumber>
        <ReachNumber>xx-xx-xx-XXXX</ReachNumber>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Name>
        </Translation>
        <Percentage>100</Percentage>
        <MolecularFormula>xxxx</MolecularFormula>
      </Substance>
    </Descomposition>
    <Waste>
      <Code>xxxxxxxxxx*</Code>
      <Translation>
        <Language>es-ES</Language>
        <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
      </Translation>
      <Dangerous>true</Dangerous>
      <Type>
        <Code>xx</Code>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxxxxxxx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Type>
      <Type>
        <Code>xx</Code>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Type>
      <Type>
        <Code>xx</Code>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxx xx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Type>
    </Waste>
    <Nfpa>
      <Health>1</Health>
      <Flammability>0</Flammability>
      <Instability>0</Instability>
      <Pictogram>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Pictogram>
    </Nfpa>
    <ProtectionEquipment>
      <Equipment>
        <xxxxxID>3</xxxxxID>
        <Type>0</Type>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Equipment>
      <Equipment>
        <xxxxxID>2</xxxxxID>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Equipment>
      <Equipment>
        <xxxxxID>7</xxxxxID>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Equipment>
      <Equipment>
        <xxxxxID>14</xxxxxID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Equipment>
      <Equipment>
        <xxxxxID>15</xxxxxID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <Translation>
          <Language>es-ES</Language>
          <Description>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Description>
        </Translation>
      </Equipment>
    </ProtectionEquipment>
    <SdsChanges>
      <Change>3</Change>
    </SdsChanges>
  </FinalProduct>
</xxxxxOutputData>
```

Comment: Me parece que tu xml no tiene nada que ver con el error. Da un error al tratar de cargar una clase.

Comment: El error  me da al hacer Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(miClase)) pero la clase en principio es funcional ya que he estado usando sus propiedades y demás. Dejo mi clase en el post.

Comment: que clase es funcional? explica mejor lo que pasa por favor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1177040/579895

Comment: Me refiero a la clase que genero con Xsd2Code a partir del xsd. Entendía que es funcional en el momento en el que he estado trabajando con ella ya que he creado varios objetos y rellenado sus propiedades manualmente. Por ello entendía que que era funcional y que el problema estaba en la serializacion que es lo que quiero conseguir para deserializar cualquier XML. Espero que se capte mi problema.

Comment: Mira la pregunta que he enlazado, y te recomiendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1155790/579895) como la mejor

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh. La verdad es que continuando con la ejecución del código funciona perfecto. Voy a echar un vistazo a la configuración del post que indicas como mejor respuesta.